# Unity3D: Pixel Byte-Array to Color32-Array (Combine ZXing with Vuforia)

Tags: unity-game-engine, pixel, qr-code, zxing, qcar-sdk

Maybe someone can help me. I need a Color32[] Array by calling GetPixels32(). Here is a good solution for an QR-Code Reader with webcam.
[How to decode QR code using Unity3D](http://ydaira.blogspot.de/2012/05/how-to-decode-qr-code-using-unity3d.html)

Vuforia can unfortunately only give a byte array with...

```
Image.PIXEL_FORMAT mPixelFormat = Image.PIXEL_FORMAT.RGB565;
Image cameraImage = CameraDevice.Instance.GetCameraImage(mPixelFormat);
byte[] pixels = cameraImage.Pixels;
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can make a Pixel byte array to an Color32 array?
[Here](https://ar.qualcomm.at/arforums/showthread.php?t=2209&referrerid=11163) is my question in the Vuforia Forum.

Maybe anyone have any other solutions for QR-Code decoding in Unity for Android and iOS.
I would be very grateful for your help.

Edit: [Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/259781/pixel-byte-array-to-color32-array-combine-zxing-wi.html) is the same Question in unityAnswers.

Comment: Please do not post the same thing in multiple places without crosslinks to each one.  (I saw this in my Unity forum RSS feed.)

Comment: ok, sorry. I edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're requesting the image data in 16-bit R5G6B5 format, so I expect that's what the data format is: pairs of bytes in 5-6-5-bit format. So, converting two bytes to a regular Color structure is something like:

```
color.r = (byte[0] & 0x1f) / (float)(0x1f);
color.g = ((byte[1] & 0x07) | ((byte[0] & 0xe0) >> 5)) / (float)(0x3f);
color.b = ((byte[1] & 0xf8) >> 3) / (float)(0x1f);
```

Then you can convert the Color to a Color32 just by casting it.

This said, if you can request the image data in a 24-bit format instead of a 16-bit format then you can just feed the byte values directly to the channels of the Color32.